# Project building but not debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have been using VS 2013 for a month now and recently, ctrl+F5 has not been working. I can build the source file successfully, but when I try to debug, either using ctrl+f5 or f5 alone, All I get is a blank console.

I have repaired the installation but to no avail.

Comment: Are any of your function keys working for anything?

Comment: I have restarted the system several times and I've also tried debugging from the toolbar.

Comment: No I mean, can you use your `f12` jump-to-method key for instance? Or any other function key within Visual Studio, or anywhere for that matter?

Comment: No. f12 has wifi. only f5 is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, there are three possible diagnoses for your problem that you can attempt to solve.

**1.** ***You have an F-Lock key on your keyboard you have accidentally pressed.***
Should this be the case, you should search whether your system does indeed have an F-Lock key and ensure that it is disabled accordingly. 

**2.** ***You somehow have an incorrect keyboard mapping / incorrect settings in VS.***
Go in **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**, select the drop-down for **Keyboard Scheme** and ensure that your keyboard mapping is correct (*the f5 key is mapped to something)*. You can always also try resetting all of your keyboard settings here. 
**3.** ***Your f5 key is broken?***
Seems kind of ridiculous to say but there's always the possibility your actual key may be simply not working.

Hopefully this helps you get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Two which I'd suggest for this would be, check the project properties launch settings "Start Action" if it's a web project.

Also to right click on the primary project you're trying to debug and "Set as Startup Project"